# How to change default mindsdb gui port

Tags: python, database, mindsdb

I am deploying MindsDB on my environment but I want to change the default port `47335` that MindsDB is starting the GUI. Can this be achieved by setting up an environment variable or do I need to change it in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by extending the default configuration that mindsdb use. Create a new file named `config.json` and get the config structure from [this location](https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb/blob/staging/mindsdb/utilities/config.py#L39). Then just change the value under HTTP port to the required port as:

```
  "api": {
                "http": {
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "port": ""
                },
```

After that just provide the location to the config as a parameter to the start command as:

```
python -m mindsdb --config=config.json
```